# angular-ui-router Error: instantiation TypeError: forEach is not a function

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using the angular seed project and try to use ui-router for user login based routing. 
I get following error in the console:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module MyApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router.state due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router.router due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.router.util due to:
TypeError: forEach is not a function
at new $UrlMatcherFactory
...
```

My code in app.js is:

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on views, and components
angular
    .module('MyApp', [
      'ui.router'
    ])
    .config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
      $stateProvider
          .state("root", {
            url: "",
            template: "<section ui-view></section>",
            controller: function($state, user) {
              if ($state.is("root")) $state.go(user.loggedIn ? "main" : "login");
            }
          })
          .state("login", {
            templateUrl: "login/login.html",
            controller: "LoginCtrl"
          })
          .state("main", {
            templateUrl: "main/main.html",
            controller: "MainCtrl"
          });
    }])
    .controller("MainCtrl", function($scope, user, $state) {
      $scope.user = user;
      $scope.logout = function() {
        user.loggedIn = false;
        $state.go("root");
      }
    })
    .controller("LoginCtrl", function($scope, user, $state) {
      $scope.login = function() {
        user.loggedIn = true;
        $state.go("root");
      }
    });
```

I didn't find anything with Google and hope someone can help me here.
Best regards

Comment: Can you try foreach? All lowercase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably a solution here ?

See this link : https://github.com/ded/script.js/issues/86

Comment: Apparently that was the problem (angular.js was loaded before angular-ui-router.js because of the async approach). Thank you!